How to use a single NLB to manage multiple microservices
When I deploy my service.yaml using kubectl apply -f service.yaml I get a connection error between my API Rest Gateway and my deployed cluster. I didn't find a specific error, it just shows status 500 InternalServerErrorException
environments

  CLUSTER_NAME: test-service
  SECURITY_GROUP_IDS: sg-xxxxxxxxxx,sg-xxxxxxxxxxx
  VPC_PRIVATE_SUBNETS: subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  VPC_PUBLIC_SUBNETS: subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx,subnet-xxxxxxxxxxxx
  NLB_NAME: "nlb-microservice"
  DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE_NAME: "eks-image"
  PORT: 8080
  TARGET_PORT: 8080
  NODE_PORT: 30164

service.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ${NLB_NAME}
  namespace: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
  labels:
    app: ${NLB_NAME}
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: ${NLB_NAME}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups: ${SECURITY_GROUP_IDS}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-protocol: "HTTP"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-port: "${PORT}"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-healthcheck-path: "/healthcheck"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: ${VPC_PRIVATE_SUBNETS},${VPC_PUBLIC_SUBNETS}
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "instance"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-target-group-attributes: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds=300,stickiness.enabled=false,proxy_protocol_v2.enabled=false,stickiness.type=source_ip,deregistration_delay.connection_termination.enabled=false,preserve_client_ip.enabled=true
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ${DEPLOYMENT_IMAGE_NAME}
  ports:
    - port: ${PORT}
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: ${TARGET_PORT}
      nodePort: ${NODE_PORT}

---
apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
  name: ${NLB_NAME}-tgb
  namespace: ${CLUSTER_NAME}
  labels:
    app: ${NLB_NAME}
spec:
  targetGroupARN: ${TARGET_GROUP_ARN}
  serviceRef:
    name: ${NLB_NAME}
    port: ${PORT}
  targetType: instance
  nodeSelector:
    matchLabels:
      beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type: t2.small
      alpha.eksctl.io/cluster-name: ${CLUSTER_NAME}

My goal is to create a single load balancer which can manage the traffic of multiple microservices through a target group that redirects the traffic. Something like this:
                          +-----------------+
                          |     Gateway     |
                          +--------+--------+
                                   |
                                   v
                          +--------+--------+
                          | Load Balancer   |
                          +--------+--------+
                                   |
          +------------------------+-------------------------+
          |                        |                         |
          v                        v                         v
 +--------+--------+      +--------+--------+       +--------+--------+
 | Cluster 1       |      | Cluster 2       |       | Cluster 3       |
 | +-------------+ |      | +-------------+ |       | +-------------+ |
 | | Microservice| |      | | Microservice| |       | | Microservice| |
 | |     A       | |      | |     B       | |       | |     C       | |
 | +-------------+ |      | +-------------+ |       | +-------------+ |
 +-----------------+      +-----------------+       +-----------------+

I tried to apply my service.yaml without specifying an existing NLB by remove these lines from the .yaml:
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-security-groups
Doing this creates a new NLB, a new target group and security groups by each microservice cluster. When I create a vpc-link linked to that new NLB the connection responds status 200 but this approach is not that im looking for do

May you visualize what you want to achieve via a diagram? This helps to simplify your question instead of so many configurations.

Sure i can diagram it
